# Make an input field on PHP form compulsory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a form which has multiple input fields.

The question I have is how can I make the form not send to the server if a certain inbox field is empty. I want to use a JavaScript pop up box to inform the user as opposed to directing to a new page were the PHP kills the script and leaves a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use client side HTML5 `required` attribute and make it do not submit.

```html
<form action="">
  <div><input type="text" required placeholder="Username" /></div>
  <div><input type="password" required placeholder="Password" /></div>
  <div>Try submitting the form, without filling in.</div>
  <div><input type="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Try submitting the form, without filling in both the boxes.

Comment: With older browsers this will not work, so it's dangerous to depend only on this, am I wrong?

Comment: @Arturo you are right. Even trusting on JS in dangerous. It is necessary to validate anything on the server, too.